# How to build a QCustom3DVolume from images?

Tags: c++, qt, visualization

I'm trying to render a stack of image as a volume in Qt.

As a starting point I've modified the "volumetric object example" and used a dataset generated at runtime (Gaussian ball) with this piece of code:

```
...

VData = new QVector<uchar>(VSize.x()*VSize.y()*VSize.z());

for (int z=0; z<VSize.z(); z++) {
    for (int y=0; y<VSize.y(); y++) {
        for (int x=0; x<VSize.x(); x++) {
            unsigned char v = 255*exp(-((x-VSize.x()/2)*(x-VSize.x()/2) + (y-VSize.y()/2)*(y-VSize.y()/2) + (z-VSize.z()/2)*(z-VSize.z()/2))/200);
            (*VData)[x + y*VSize.x() + z*VSize.x()*VSize.y()] = v;
        }
    }
}

Volume = new QCustom3DVolume;
Volume->setTextureData(new QVector<uchar>(*VData));

...
```

and the result is fine:

[image]

Now I'd like to do the same thing but with a stack of 2D images. I am currently blocked at a point where I need to convert the images into a QVector, to feed the method `setTextureData(QVector<uchar> *data)`.

In the [documentation of the QCustom3DVolume](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qcustom3dvolume.html#textureData-prop) class it is written:

> A 3D texture is defined by a stack of 2D subtextures. Each subtexture
>   must be of identical size (textureDataWidth * textureHeight), and the
>   depth of the stack is defined by the textureDepth property. The data
>   in each 2D texture is identical to a QImage data with the same format,
>   so QImage::bits() can be used to supply the data for each subtexture.

There is no more detail and I don't understand how this could be implemented. A pointer to an image would only provide one layer (subtexture), so how can I get the whole volume in the QVector? Is my only option here to loop over the images and copy the bytes in a QVector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just discovered the [setSubTextureData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qcustom3dvolume.html#setSubTextureData) method in the documentation, which is exactly what I was looking for.